# dhcp takes so long to obtain IP

Tags: networking, dhcp

on RPi3 I'm running Raspbian Jessie Lite.
I configured the network to use dhcp on WiFi.

It works but it takes very long time to get the IP, ofter over 30-40 secs!
Usually my PCs, phones and other WiFi equipment get it in a couple of seconds.

Is there some flags to pass to dhclient to speed up the process?

EDIT:
sometimes it fails with the error "No DHCPOFFERS received"